# Can I delete the Z: drive from the wine installation? Wine-mono doesn't install and some other win programs don't work

Tags: linux, windows, wine

There's a z:drive set as default when wine first runs. In winecfg, at least in my installation, shows that it is linked to /dev/dm-1.

When I removed this drive, and shifted the wine-mono-7.1.1-x86.msi file into the wine prefix drive c:/users/Public directory to run, `wine msiexec /i wine-mono-7.1.1-x86.msi`, the installation fails without displaying the usual gui installation window.

Is there a need to have the z drive in place?

> 010c:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot

appears as well as the usual fixme error messages.

Comment: There are files in root folder that wine needs for running itself. I myself is looking for a solution.